# VPN from Azure to AWS

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services, azure

Is there a way to connect Azure to AWS with Site-to-site VPN ?

All guides and resources I have found in internet so far are using a VM that runs ipsec software (openswan/strongswan/RRAS), but I would like to explore native options first as that seem more elegant.

**Note**: "[Is it possible to create a VPN link between AZURE VNET and AWS VPC?](https://serverfault.com/questions/701246/is-it-possible-to-create-a-vpn-link-between-azure-vnet-and-aws-vpc)" may be seen as a duplicate, but I don't feel there is a satisfactory answer there. I could not get connection working using suggestions in that thread.

Comment: It may be indeed seen as a duplicate, but I don't feel there is a satisfactory answer there. I could not get connection working using suggestions in that thread.

Comment: I'd suspect there's a reason all the tutorials involve a VM running OpenSwan etc.

Comment: [This answer](http://serverfault.com/a/727094/153161), while not the accepted one, appears to be correct, if both sides have incompatible, non-configurable tunnel parameters.  You don't need a vm on both sides, but will need a vm on at least one side, configured to talk with the gateway on the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't connect using native options. Both AWS and Azure wants to be the guy dictating how the connection is going to be while demanding you to adjust your side accordingly. Since you cannot change anything on any side, the connection never happens due to the incompatibility of parameters.

The only way is having a virtual appliance for this job. I'd recommend creating a Windows Server with RRAS on AWS side and the native VPN gateway on Azure side.

Basically:

1. Launch a Windows Server 2012 R2 instance on AWS
2. Apply an Elastic IP to it
3. Configure Azure Gateway, Local gateway and the Connection
4. Download [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/Azure-vpn-config-samples/master/Microsoft/microsoft-rras-windows-server-2012-r2.ps1.xslt) script to install and configure RRAS on the instance. Make sure to adjust line 77 and beyond according to your scenario
5. Add route tables to Azure in AWS VPC

Not sure if I missed anything, but, in general, should be it.

Comment: I went with the Linux based VM and libreswan as ipsec vpn, but used same idea.